# Linux mint 18.1 with menu bar on the side can we show application text?

Tags: linux-mint

Using Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon

I put my menu bar on the side rather than the bottom. However on the side there is no text associated with each icon as there is across the bottom.

Is it possible to expand the menu bar so that text is shown the same as it's on the bottom?

Sidebar appearance:

[image]

Bottom appearance:

[image]

Comment: Or I might ask: are there better menu bar options (e.g. alternative packages) I might install that would allow a more usable left/right side menu bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response to this on the linux mint forums, it's simply not possible in LM 18.1.